Use ProgressListener with multiobjective in docplex (CPLEX)
I am translating an implementation of a gurobi model to cplex which uses multi-objective functionality and uses the following callbacks. The purpose of the callbacks is to extract the information from the optimization process as the different objectives are optimized.
Gurobi part
def _optimize_callback(model: gb.Model, where: int):
    
    if where == GRB.Callback.MULTIOBJ:
        # change of objective index (multiobjective)
        model._obj_index = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MULTIOBJ_OBJCNT)

    elif where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        obj_best_value = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPSOL_OBJBST)  # Current best objective
        obj_bound_value = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPSOL_OBJBND)  # Current objective bound

        #best solution found
        assign_var_values = model.cbGetSolution(context.assign_vars)
        solution = [combination for combination in context.assign_vars.keys() if assign_var_values[combination] > 0.99]

        report_info(model._obj_index, obj_best_value, obj_bound_value, solution)

   elif where == GRB.Callback.MIP:
        #update indicators without update sol
        obj_best_value = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIP_OBJBST)  # Current best objective
        obj_bound_value = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIP_OBJBND) 
       
        report_info(model._obj_index, obj_best_value, obj_bound_value)

I have a test code which uses ProgressListener from docplex. I am new with this module but I think I can already achieve the MIP and MIPSOL callback functionality in gurobi but I have not been able to access the optimization of the different objectives index by index.
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.progress import *
import numpy as np

class InfoCallback(SolutionRecorder):

    def __init__(self, model):
        super(InfoCallback, self).__init__(ProgressClock.Gap)
        self.last_obj = None
        self.best_bound = None
        self.mip_gap = None
        self.model = model
        self.current_obj_index = -1
        
    def notify_start(self):
        super(InfoCallback, self).notify_start()
        self.last_obj = None
        self.current_obj_index = 0  # Start with the first objective
        
    def is_improving(self, new_obj, eps=1e-4):
        last_obj = self.last_obj
        return last_obj is None or (abs(new_obj- last_obj) >= eps)
    
    def notify_progress(self, pdata):
        super(InfoCallback, self).notify_progress(pdata)
        if pdata.has_incumbent and self.is_improving(pdata.current_objective):
            self.last_obj = pdata.current_objective
            self.mip_gap = pdata.mip_gap
            self.best_bound = pdata.best_bound

            print('----> #new objective={0}, bound={1}s, objective={2}, mip={3}'.format(self.last_obj, self.best_bound, self.current_obj_index, self.mip_gap))
        else:
            # a non improving move
            self.best_bound = pdata.best_bound
            self.mip_gap = pdata.mip_gap
            print('----> #new objective={0}, bound={1}s, objective={2}, mip={3}'.format(self.last_obj, self.best_bound, self.current_obj_index, self.mip_gap))
                        
    def notify_solution(self, s):
        super().notify_solution(s)
        obj_value = s.get_objective_value()
        
        # Get the current objective index from the solution
        print(f"New incumbent solution found with objective value: {obj_value}")
        multi_obj_values = s.multi_objective_values
        
        if multi_obj_values:
            self.current_obj_index = multi_obj_values.index(max(multi_obj_values))
            print(multi_obj_values, self.current_obj_index)
            
            #for var in self.model.iter_variables():
            #    print(f"{var.name}: {s.get_value(var)}")        

np.random.seed(0)

# Example data
num_vehicles = 10
num_customers = 40
locations = range(num_customers + 1)  # Including the depot
distance_matrix = np.random.randint(10, 100, size=(num_customers + 1, num_customers + 1))
time_matrix = np.random.randint(200, 600, size=(num_customers + 1, num_customers + 1))
gas_matrix = np.random.randint(50, 600, size=(num_customers + 1, num_customers + 1))

# Create the model
model = Model(name="VRP")

# Variables
x = model.binary_var_dict(((i, j, k) for i in locations for j in locations for k in range(num_vehicles) if i != j), name="x")
u = model.continuous_var_dict((i for i in locations), name="u")  # Subtour elimination variables

# Objective: Minimize total distance
# Define objectives
cost_obj = model.sum(distance_matrix[i][j] * x[i, j, k] for i in locations for j in locations for k in range(num_vehicles) if i != j)
time_obj = model.sum(time_matrix[i][j] * x[i, j, k] for i in locations for j in locations for k in range(num_vehicles) if i != j)
gas_obj = model.sum(gas_matrix[i][j] * x[i, j, k] for i in locations for j in locations for k in range(num_vehicles) if i != j)


# Set multiple objectives with priorities
model.set_multi_objective("min", [cost_obj, time_obj, gas_obj], priorities=[2, 1, 4], names = ['Cost', 'Time', 'Gas'])

# Constraints
# Each customer is visited exactly once
for j in locations[1:]:
    model.add_constraint(model.sum(x[i, j, k] for i in locations for k in range(num_vehicles) if i != j) == 1, f"visit_{j}")

# Each vehicle starts from the depot and ends at the depot
for k in range(num_vehicles):
    model.add_constraint(model.sum(x[0, j, k] for j in locations[1:]) == 1, f"start_{k}")
    model.add_constraint(model.sum(x[i, 0, k] for i in locations[1:]) == 1, f"end_{k}")

# Subtour elimination constraints (MTZ formulation)
for i in locations[1:]:
    for j in locations[1:]:
        if i != j:
            for k in range(num_vehicles):
                model.add_constraint(u[i] - u[j] + num_customers * x[i, j, k] <= num_customers - 1, f"subtour_{i}_{j}_{k}")

# Solve the model
solution_recorder = InfoCallback(model)
model.add_progress_listener(solution_recorder)
solution = model.solve(clean_before_solve=True)

print(f"Objective Value: {solution.objective_value}")
print(solution.multi_objective_values)
print(solution.solve_details.status)

Executing the code I can see the evolution of the optimization process but it only allows me to access the information of one objective. However, at the end, the three optimized objectives appear.
----> #new objective=10892.0, bound=3952.0s, objective=0, mip=0.6371648916636005
New incumbent solution found with objective value: 10892.0
[10892.0] 0
----> #new objective=2861.0, bound=2861.0s, objective=0, mip=0.0
New incumbent solution found with objective value: 2861.0
[2861.0] 0
Objective Value: 2861.0
[2861.0, 22483.0, 3952.0]
multi-objective optimal
How can I access the optimization process objective by objective? I understand that cplex generates a lexicographic order of the objectives by priority and optimizes one by one but my code only gives me information about the objective with the highest priority. Thank you for any help please.

There is indeed a problem with the function s.multi_objective_values that can be called from inside a callback. Whatever the interface one uses, multi-objective values of solutions cannot be accessed from inside a callback in CPLEX.

You can get the latest of the kpi change.
If I mix https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooprogresslistener.py and https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoomultiobjective.py
I can write
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from docplex.mp.progress import *

mdl = Model(name='buses')

nbbus50 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus50')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')

cost = mdl.continuous_var(name='cost')
co2emission = mdl.continuous_var(name='co2emission')

mdl.add_constraint(nbbus50*50+nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 200, 'kids')
mdl.add_constraint(co2emission==nbbus50+nbbus40*1.1+nbbus30*1.2)
mdl.add_constraint(cost==nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400+nbbus50*625)
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40!=0)
                
sense="min"
exprs=[cost,co2emission]
priorities=[1,2]
weights=[1,1]
timelimits=[0.005, 10]
reltols=[0.00001, 0.0005]

mdl.set_multi_objective(sense, exprs, priorities, weights, abstols=None,
                        reltols=None, names=None)

params = mdl.build_multiobj_paramsets(timelimits = timelimits, mipgaps=reltols)

#mdl.solve( log_output=True, parameter_sets=params)

class pl(ProgressListener):
  
    def __init__(self):
        ProgressListener.__init__(self, ProgressClock.Gap)
    
    def notify_progress(self, pdata):
        gap = pdata.mip_gap
        ms_time = 1000* pdata.time
        print('-- new gap: {0:.1%}, time: {1:.0f} ms'.format(gap, ms_time))
        print("-- current objective = ",pdata.current_objective)
        

# connect a listener to the model
mdl.add_progress_listener(pl())


mdl.solve(log_output=False,)

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print("The minimum cost is ",cost.solution_value);
print("CO2 emission is ",co2emission.solution_value);

which gives
- new gap: 21.8%, time: 2 ms
-- current objective =  5.5
-- new gap: 15.7%, time: 2 ms
-- current objective =  5.1
-- new gap: 16.7%, time: 9 ms
-- current objective =  3000.0
nbBus50  =  4.0
nbBus40  =  1.0
nbBus30  =  0
The minimum cost is  3000.0
CO2 emission is  5.1

